# iteration problems with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to make a function that creates a sql statement to insert data into a database and this is a snippet. It works fine except for the last foreach loop. For some reason it won't iterate to the last element in the array it'll stay stuck on the second last one. The issue is that the first foreach loop is the same code and it works fine, but the second is giving me trouble.

*note:The if statements in the foreach loops are supposed to catch the last element in the array and make sure that a ',' isn't inserted. And this is where the problem is. If I take the if statement out of the second loop the loop will iterate to the last element but without the if block it places a comma at the end and creates a SQL syntax error.

output of the first loop

```
INSERT INTO gardyloo.users (joe,bob,joe@hotmail.com,8de,154927,2014-12-18,2014-12-18 7:02:11)
```

output of second loop without if

```
VALUES (:firstName,:lastName,:emailAddress,:password,:userid,:date_joined,:timestamp,)
```

output of second loop with if

```
VALUES (:firstName,:lastName,:emailAddress,:password,:userid,:date_joined)  

foreach( $values as $a => $b ){

        if(next($values) == null){
            $sql .= $b."";
            break;
        }
        $sql .= $b.",";
    }
    $sql .= ") ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (";
    foreach( $values as $a => $b ){

        if(next($values) == null){
            $sql .= ":".$a;
            break;
        }
        $sql .= ":".$a.",";
    }
$sql .= ")";
```

*Edit, this code seems to work fine:

```
$sql .= implode(', ', array_keys($values));
$sql .= ") ";
$sql .= "VALUES (:";
$sql .= implode(", :", array_keys($values)); 
$sql .= ")";
```

Comment: You should NEVER do this in a production environment. You're opening yourself up to a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Always use Parameterized Statements.

Comment: what do you mean by Parameterized Statements?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: I should mention the line right after 
$sql .= ")"; is 
$query = $init->link->prepare($sql);
Does that mean anything?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP, but essentially, I would recommend the following:

$query = $init->link->prepare("INSERT INTO gardyloo.users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

Then, run a for-loop (if you have multiple rows to add, otherwise no for-loop) to run the query

`$query->execute($firstName, $lastName, $emailAddress, $password, $userId, $dateJoined, $timestamp);`

Comment: Also, you never want to store passwords in plain text, in case someone manages to intercept your database. I'd recommend reading [this post](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), which details why that's a bad idea, and how to fix it.

Comment: Please show us your array of value to reproduce the problem. And don't forget, `next` is set the pointer to the `next` item! Don't you want to set back with `prev`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of break you need to use continue; Break interrupts the loop, while continue only move to next iteration.

Try this:

```
foreach( $values as $a => $b ){

    if($b == null){
        continue;
    }
    $sql .= ":".$a.",";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. It does help iterate to the last element, but it isn't doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
       //Your data 
       $values = array(
                       'firstName'    => 'Joe', 
                       'lastName'     => 'bob', 
                       'emailAddress' => 'joe@hotmail.com', 
                       'password'     => '8de', 
                       'userid'       => 154927, 
                       'date_joined'  => '2014-12-18', 
                       'timestamp'    => '2014-12-18 7:02:11'
                       );

        //Begins the sentence
        $sql    = 'INSERT INTO gardyloo.users(';

        /**
         * Begins example code.
         * - array_keys shows the key as a value
         *   example: $values[0] = firstName
         */
        foreach(array_keys($values) as $k => $v)
        {
            //when the array arrives at the end, doesn't show ','
            if($k != count($values)-1)
                $sql .= $v.",";
            else
                $sql .= $v;
        }

        $sql .= ") ";
        $sql .= "VALUES (";
        $k = 0;//the new count initialized

        foreach($values as $v)
        {
            //when the array arrives at the end, doesn't show ','
            if($k != count($values)-1)
                $sql .= $v.",";
            else
                $sql .= $v;
            //increments the counter
            $k++;
        }

        $sql .= ");";
```

**Notes:**

- Separate the code in functions since both foreachs are very similar.
- You can play with the foreach values to return the value that you want.
- Ask me if you have more questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it otherwise. Instead of concat a string `$sql` create 2 variables, $columns and $values, both are arrays. And you don't need a loop to do this.

So here is how i would do it :

```
$columns = array_keys($values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (". implode(" ,", $columns) . ") VALUES (". implode(" ,", $values);
```

Here you don't need to test if it's the last element of the array to make a `break;`

Hope it helps ;)